# Keras model to tensorflow.keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a model that I made with `Keras` (using `Tensorflow` as backend).
Now I want to use the `Keras` inside the `Tensorflow` release.

However, replacing this line

```
from keras.engine.topology import get_source_inputs
```

with this line

```
from tensorflow.keras.engine.topology import get_source_inputs
```

does not work. It says

```
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.engine'
```

where can I find the `get_source_inputs` function in `Tensorflow`?

Comment: `get_source_inputs` (and the whole `engine.topology`) seems [deprecated](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/topology.py).

Comment: You can import it as `from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import get_source_inputs`

Comment: Did you figure out where we can import the get_source_inputs? I have the same problem

Comment: Nope, I decided to refactor the complete model

Answer (score 5):

Updating Keras to version 2.2.4 seems to do the trick for me!

You can then import the `get_source_inputs` function in one of the following ways:

```
from keras.utils import get_source_inputs
from keras.utils.layer_utils import get_source_inputs
```

or if you are not using Keras as an external library but the TF version of it, then you can import the function with:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import get_source_inputs
```

Hope this helps!